# Lumen request all, input, file null

Tags: api, request, upload, lumen

I have a really weird problem. I've search already the whole web for the solution and found nothing.

I am not newbie in PHP.

I use Lumen in my application. To send the data I use Postman.

The problem is:

$request->file() and $request->allFiles() returns NULL.

But if I use PHP $_FILES then it shows all.

Route:
`$router->post('/import/create', 'CalendarController@importCreate');`

Controller:

```
public function importCreate(Request $request)
{
        // Get uploaded CSV file
        $files = $request->allFiles();

        return response($files);
    }
```

This is what I get back:

```
{
    "files": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

(empty json array)

But if I do like this:

```
return response($_FILES);
```

Then it works:

```
{
    "files": {
        "name": [
            "logo.png"
        ],
        "type": [
            "image/png"
        ],
        "tmp_name": [
            "/tmp/phpjcjN4q"
        ],
        "error": [
            0
        ],
        "size": [
            7278
        ]
    }
}
```

What we can exclude::

1. I use good Request import:
   `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`
2. php.ini settings are OK:
   [image: phpinfo1]
   [image: phpinfo2]
   [image: phpinfo3]

The file I tried to upload has only 7KB, so its not the problem.

3. I use POST, and not PUT, so its not the problem.

Postman Request:
[image: Postman Request]

What I also noticed that $request->all() and $request->input() both returns also NULL, even if I post anything.

As I said I am not newbie in this, and I really appreciate your help.

Anyone got any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, it has been fixed somehow. Don't know how, don't know when.

I updated composer dependencies with `composer update` but I'm not sure if that was the case.